# Python Pandas Melt a Sparse Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, transform, melt

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
   a    b        z
1 NULL NULL  ... 1
2 NULL  1    ... NULL
3  1   NULL  ... NULL
```

The first column is always populated and there are many others to the right of it. Of columns a through z one is populated the rest are not.

I would like to transform this dataframe into a two-column data frame with the headers of columns a through z in the second column. The example above would be transformed to this.

```
  The_Column
1    z
2    b
3    a
```

The pandas.melt() function is close to what I need, but it doesn't handle the NULL values. I only care about the one cell in columns B through Z which is populated.

Is there an elegant way to handle this problem?

Comment: That's not a DataFrame. Please provide a [mcve] that accurately represents your problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need melt, and then df.dropna() - that's it

this should work:

```
df.set_index('a').melt().dropna().reset_index()
```

Comment: sorry, i meant dropna(), not drop_duplicates()

Answer (score 0):

Using `stack` (which drops NA's by default):

```
x = (df.set_index('a')
         .stack()
         .reset_index()
         .drop(columns=0)
         .rename(columns={'level_1': 'The_Column'})

print(x)
```

Output:

```
   a The_Column
0  1          z
1  2          b
2  3          c
```